# How to capture a pattern not pereceded by a fix string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Assume this string

```
http://foobar.com
```

Catching the domain only **not** following `foo` is of interest, so in this case ***nothing*** must be captured.

using lookbehind as

```
(?<!foo)[a-z]+\.[a-z]+
```

would result to

```
foobar.com
```

since no `foo` is seen behind when it is at the position of 7 at the string.

Comment: What about `http://afoobar.com`? Should that match or not?

Comment: You need some kind of anchor that says where the match should start. Then use a negative lookaround to reject if `foo` is found there. Otherwise it will match something not after `foo` anywhere in the string.

Comment: @Barmar it should match & capture `afoobar.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookbehind to require the match to be after `/`, and a negative lookahead to prohibit `foo` at the beginning.

```
(?<=\/)(?!foo)[a-z]+\.[a-z]+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/1nPyu3/1)